# Python mock running in pytest crashing my instance

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, patch

I've got the following test module, running in Python 2.7 on FreeBSD:

```
from mock import patch

from t.conf import load_config


@patch('t.conf._load_file')
def test_open_file(mock_open):
    string_read = load_config('foo')
    print(repr(string_read))
```

It runs fine if I comment out the `patch` line. It crashes my machine after hanging for about 10 minutes if I leave it in. I'm using `patch` in other places without any issues. What's going on?

`_load_file` looks like this:

```
def _load_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()
```

And `load_config` looks like this:

```
def load_config(filename):
    text = _load_file(filename)
    data = yaml.safe_load(text)
    return data
```

Comment: Who knows--it may be impossible to say without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Sounds like an infinite recursion.

Comment: Patch returns a Mock() instance when called, so you might have logic that's retrying forever because it doesn't get a response it likes...? Hard to say without seeing the rest. Maybe add a return value or side effect. And in general try to refactor such that you're testing with `mock` and not `patch`

Comment: Can you please add the content of `load_config()` function? Also, what do you mean by "crashes my machine"? How does it look like?

Comment: Added the contents of the functions being called/mocked. And by "Crashes my machine" I mean it's running in a jail on a shared server, and if I don't CTRL-C the process while it's running, it brings down the entire server.